# trying to send email with laravel, get an error. What does this mean?

Tags: email, laravel

I'm trying to send email with laravel, get an error. What does this mean?

```
stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given
```

Edit: Mail code.

controller:

```
public function postSubmit(Request $request)
    {
        Mail::send('emails.contact', ['data' => $request->all()], function ($m) {
            $m->from(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'));

            $m->to('xxxxx', 'xxxx')->subject('Contact Form Submitted');
        });
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@index');
Route::post('/contact/submit', 'ContactController@postSubmit');
```

View:

```
 <form role="form" id="feedbackForm" data-toggle="validator" data-disable="false" method="POST" action="{{ url('contact/submit') }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Send view:

```
<strong>You have a new feedback from contact page!</strong>
<p><strong>Name: </strong> {{$data['name']}}</p>
<p><strong>Email: </strong> {{$data['email']}}</p>
<p><strong>Message: </strong> {{$data['message']}}</p>
```

Edit2: disable_functions: "phpinfo, system, exec, passthru, proc_open, shell_exec, popen, setlimit, mysql_pconnect, stream_socket_client"

These functions are disabled by the host. (They won't enable them due security reasons). I've been informed that I can use mail(). How does that work exactly?! (smtp, username, password, etc..)

Comment: can you please post your complete mail send code?

Comment: I edited the main text

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you solve it? please provide the solution.

Comment: @AjmalRazeel I did. see answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to get laravel to send an email.

Yes, of course. Here's the solution that I used in order to configure email for laravel.

indexmail.php, root folder

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';

 $to="your-email@your-domain.com";
 $subject="Enquiry!";
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: ".$email_from."\r\n";
 $message="   

         Name:
         $name     
         <br>
         Email-Id:
         $email        
         <br>
         Message:
         $query        

   ";
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Successful Submission! Thankyou for contacting us.");
    else
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Error To send Email !");
        //contact:-your-email@your-domain.com
 }
?>
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('/contact/submit', 'ContactController@postSubmit');
```

config/mail.php

```
'from' => ['address' => 'Sender@email.com', 'name' => 'MyName'],




'pretend' => false,
```

email view.

```
<strong>You have a new feedback from contact page!</strong>
<p><strong>Name: </strong> {{$data['name']}}</p>
<p><strong>Email: </strong> {{$data['email']}}</p>
<p><strong>Message: </strong> {{$data['message']}}</p>
```

contact form.

```
 <form role="form" id="feedbackForm" data-toggle="validator" data-disable="false" method="POST"
                                 action="{{ url('contact/submit') }}">
                               <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

app/Http/Requests/ContactFormRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class ContactFormRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

app/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Let me know if it works! [original refference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34106977/trying-to-configure-mail-in-laravel-get-an-exception-why)